# Extracting Zip File Not Working for me in android?

Tags: android, unzip, zip

I want to download zip file from server and extract in sdcard programmatically but it will not extracting zip file.

I have check this tutorial

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29

I have use below code but it is not work for me

```
UnZipActivity.java

public class UnZipActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        UnZip un = new UnZip("/storage/emulated/0/peakmedia/news.zip","/storage/emulated/0/peakmedia/");
        un.unzip();
    }
}
```

> UnZip.java

```
public class UnZip {

    public String _zipFile; 
    public String _location; 

    public UnZip(String zipFile, String location) {
      _zipFile = zipFile; 
      _location = location; 
    } 

    public void unzip() { 

      try  { 
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); 
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
        ZipEntry ze = null; 
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
          Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName()); 
          if(ze.isDirectory()) { 
            _dirChecker(ze.getName()); 
          } else { 
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName()); 
            for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) { 
              fout.write(c); 
            } 
            zin.closeEntry(); 
            fout.close(); 
          } 

        } 
        zin.close(); 
      } catch(Exception e) { 
        Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
      } 

    } 

    private void _dirChecker(String dir) { 
      File f = new File(_location + dir); 

      if(!f.isDirectory()) { 
        f.mkdirs(); 
      } 
    } 

}
```

> Logcat Error :

```
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936): unzip
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/peakmedia/news/jquery.backstretch.min.js: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at com.peak.media.UnZip.unzip(UnZip.java:49)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at com.peak.media.UnZipActivity.onCreate(UnZipActivity.java:14)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:158)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
02-03 15:23:09.125: E/Decompress(4936):     ... 19 more
```

Comment: and what does Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e) show?

Comment: Does your **Unzip** routine work on **rar** files, too? `UnZip un = new UnZip("/storage/emulated/0/peakmedia/news.rar"`

Comment: i try with .zip file and now it will give me error

Comment: what error? what does Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e) show?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/peakmedia/news/jquery.backstretch.min.js: open failed: ENOENT, it shows where the problem is, doesn't it?

Comment: but file is there which name is jquery,backstretch.min.js in zip folder i download manually

Comment: i didn't understand any word from your last comment, sorry

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/peakmedia/news/jquery.backstretch.min.js: open failed: ENOENT,   this error means file is not open am i right but in pc file is completely open

Comment: first, do you have folder named: /storage/emulated/0/peakmedia/news/ ?

Comment: i got the issue for that before extracting the zip i need to create same folder in sdcard thanks

Comment: Always get same error FileNotFoundException, I don't know why I have all permisions include "fly in the space"